# Similar to Control.Invoke for my custom class

Tags: .net

If i want to create a class ( just for testing and understanding purpose) that should behave like a control in a sense that whenever i try to do cross-thread access, I should be able to throw an exception.  how do i implement in .NET C#.  ( Dont Derive from control class. The similarity ends with respect to cross-thread access)

For example I have a class Employee, when somebody access the object from other than the thread created, I need to behave like control and throw an exception? Pls Help

Comment: How about inheriting from `System.ComponentModel.Component`? Why do you need to throw an exception for cross-thread access? The only way to get the functionality of `Control.Invoke` for free is by inheriting from a class that implements it.

Comment: Purely for a learning purpose. Or How can Implement Invoke function by mysefl? So that i can execute in a particular context, as requested by the callers!

Comment: Is it very similar? [Detect Cross Thread operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922219/how-to-detect-cross-thread-access-in-net-enforce-thread-affinity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the value of the Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId in the constructor, and then compare the thread id when a function is called with the stored value? If they are different throw an exception.